# flutter - how to save a class in a variable

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have a list of items in my app. on each item, will lead to a different page, how can I store the class name into a variable. if there is any other solution regarding my problem i will gladly accept it. thank you

this is my list item code

```
                  ItemMenu(
                    image: "assets/images/logo.png",
                    title: "Agama",
                    page: "Agama_page()",
                  ),
                  ItemMenu(
                    image: "assets/images/logo.png",
                    title: "Gender",
                    page: "Gender_page()",
                  ),
                  ItemMenu(
                    image: "assets/images/logo.png",
                    title: "Geografi",
                    page: "Geografi_page()",
                  )
```

and this is class for item menu code

```
 class ItemMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String page;
  const ItemMenu({
    Key key,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.page,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        
        Get.to(() => page));
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        // width: 100,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, bottom: 10, top: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 10),
                blurRadius: 20,
                color: Color(0xFF4056C6).withOpacity(.15),
              )
            ]),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              image,
              height: 90,
            ),
            Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no `if`-`else` used in the code you've shown, so it's unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: ok, I've edited the question

Comment: It's still unclear what you're asking for.  What does storing a class name in a variable have to do with the code you've posted?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: the answer from muhammad ali raza is in accordance with my question, but i want to get another solution besides using if else, because in my opinion it is not efficient if there are too many items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a callback type of the param page

```
ItemMenu(
  image: "assets/images/logo.png",
  title: "Agama",
  page: () => Agama_page(),
),

//...
class ItemMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  //...
  final Widget Function() page
...
```

=== update the full class

```
class ItemMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final Widget Function() page;
  const ItemMenu({
    Key key,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.page,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        
        Get.to(page);
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        // width: 100,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, bottom: 10, top: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 10),
                blurRadius: 20,
                color: Color(0xFF4056C6).withOpacity(.15),
              )
            ]),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              image,
              height: 90,
            ),
            Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you write the code for the itemmenu class completely? because I'm still confused

Answer (score 1):

Your question was unclear but in your code I saw you are not doing the navigation correctly.

you are giving string insteadof widget to Get.to() method.

try updating your code like this.

```js
class ItemMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image;
  final String title;
  final String page;
  const ItemMenu({
    Key key,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.page,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        //! change this part in your code
        //Get.to(() => page)); <- change this 
    
        if(page == 'Agama_page()'){      // <- to this
           Get.to(() => AgamaPage());
        }
        //TODO: do the rest off you navigation below
    
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        // width: 100,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, bottom: 10, top: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(0, 10),
                blurRadius: 20,
                color: Color(0xFF4056C6).withOpacity(.15),
              )
            ]),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              image,
              height: 90,
            ),
            Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// and of course create separate screen for every  navigation  
class AgamaPage extends StatelessWidget{
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    body:Center(child:Text('AgamaPage'))   );
}
```

or you can define routes and use Get.toNamed()

Comment: thanks, I've used this method before, but when I have a lot of items, it's not efficient in my opinion, is there any other way besides if else

Comment: you can replace if else with switch statement and convert the strings to enums,

But in my opinion, define routes in GetMaterialApp in main and use Get.toNamed() method for navigation.